# java csv value comparison for multivalued rows

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file which have these following fields. so here i trimmed down only the required fields.

```
"id.attr.id","id.attr.id1","id.attr.id2","id.attr.id7","id.attr.arry","id.attr.arry1","id.attr.arry2","id.attr.arry5","id.attr.arry4"

"0",,,"8",,,"8",,"0"
"3",,,"7",,,"7",,"3"
"4",,,"8",,,"8",,"4"
"5",,"7","5",,,"7",,"5"
"4",,,"8",,,"4",,"8"
"3",,,"7",,,"7",,"3"
```

Now to define the problem . So for "id.attr.id" group that means for these fields `("id.attr.id","id.attr.id1","id.attr.id2","id.attr.id7")`
&`"id.attr.arry"`group means`("id.attr.arry","id.attr.arry1","id.attr.arry2","id.attr.arry5","id.attr.arry4")`  i need to return all the multi field values.

so what i have done is this.

```
//to map the header

private void parseUsingOpenCSV(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        boolean processHeader = false;
        Map<Integer, String> columnIndexMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //here we process only header line and prepare columnIndexMap
            if (!processHeader) {
                processHeader = true;
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));
                String[] row = reader.readNext();
                for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                    String columnName = row[i];
                    if (columnName.matches("id.attr.id(.*)")) {
                        columnIndexMap.put(i, columnName);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //here we process al data lines and maintain a buffer
                count++;
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
                if (count % 500 == 0) {
                    process(builder.toString(), columnIndexMap);
                    builder = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
        }
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            process(builder.toString(), columnIndexMap);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void process(String records, Map<Integer, String> columnIndexMap) throws IOException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(records));
    Map<String, String> columnValueMap;
    for (String[] row : reader.readAll()) {
        columnValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            if (columnIndexMap.containsKey(i)) {
                String value = row[i];
                if (value.trim().length() > 0) {
                    columnValueMap.put(columnIndexMap.get(i), value);
                }
            }
        }
    //    if (columnValueMap >i) {

            System.out.println("columnValueMap = " + columnValueMap);


   //     }
    }
}
}
```

So this program is returning all the values in the "id.attr.id" group.
    Now what the columnValueMap returns is the value of all the mapped columns. 
 how am going to get the multivalued result

as expected results are:

So the program should return from the above given csv.

```
4,8
5,7,51
4,8
3,7
```

Also can u please provide me with the possible changes in the that need to be done to check weather any values from "id.attr.id" group are matching with "id.attr.arry" group if so then we need to return them too

```
0
3
4,8
5,7
4,8
3,7
```

Comment: It sounds like you've figured out how to read the CSV file. So why don't you simplify your question by stripping out all that code and focussing on your remaining problem?

Comment: well i have updated the question. but i'm still not able to get my answer. i just now don't know what to do.. :(

Comment: I think you missed my point. Based on your descriptions, you know how to read your CSV file into, say, a String array? If so, we don't need to see *any* code that works with your CSV file. **Reduce** your problem down to the essentials. Note: this **will** involve writing a new program simply for demonstration purposes. Hope that makes sense. If not, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please follow Duncan's instructions and produce an mcve clearly indicating what's the desired behavior and what's going wrong.

Comment: I can only suggest to store the CSV content in `Map<String, List<String>>` structure that the given data may look like this:
`{ "id.attr.id"  : List<String>("0", "3", "4", "5", "4", "3"),
"id.attr.id1" : List<String>("", "", "", "", "", ""),
"id.attr.id2" : List<String>("", "", "", "", "", ""),
"id.attr.id7"  : List<String>("8", "7", "8", "7", "8", "7"),
...
}`
I think this way it will easier to (post) process your data.

Comment: i can understand. but i'm a novice to java. & still trying to learn. how ever using regex does simplifies the code. even for post processing i'm mapping the required field. isn't i?